# Use files on host system with running containers using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I want to use excel file and some folders with my container .
I am using volumes but , dont know what the problem is with my compose .

```
seleniumhub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
    - "4444:4444"

firefoxnode:
  image: selenium/node-firefox-debug
  ports:
    - "5901:5900"
  links:
    - "seleniumhub:hub"
  shm_size: '2gb'        
  environment:
   - "NODE_MAX_SESSION=2"
   - "NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=2"

chromenode2:
  image: selenium/node-chrome-debug
  ports:
    - "5902:5900"
  links:
    - "seleniumhub:hub"
  shm_size: '2gb'
  environment:
    - "NODE_MAX_SESSION=2"
    - "NODE_MAX_INSTANCES=2"

test:
  image: raveena1/dilsel
  ports:
    - 4579
  links:
    - "seleniumhub:hub"
  container_name: mywebcontainer
  **volumes:
    - /$$(pwd)/Newfolder/Config/framework-config.properties:/var/lib/docker/**
```

I want to use the above property file in my container , how can i achieve this ?

Comment: can you format your question better and be more preceise of what exactly you want

Answer (score 0):

I don't think docker-compose can interpret bash command inside a compose file. However, what you can do is use environment variable. In your case, you might want to use `$PWD`.

```
[...]
volumes:
  - $PWD/Newfolder/Config/framework-config.properties:/var/lib/docker/
[...]
```

This will interpret the environment variable `$PWD` (which resolves to your current working directy) and mount this to `/var/lib/docker`.

Below is an example of using environment variable in docker-compose :

docker-compose.yml:

```
test:
  image: debian:stretch-slim
  ports:
    - 4579
  container_name: mywebcontainer
  volumes:
    - $PWD/:/current_directory_of_host
  entrypoint: "ls -l /current_directory_of_host"
```

Start this container with `docker-compose up`. You should see a list of file that is in your current working directory.

You can also use custom environment variable : `CUSTOM_ENV=$(pwd) docker-compose up`. This will forward `CUSTOM_ENV` to docker-compose which can be used in your docker-compose.yml.